# Video playback on HDMI connected TV freezes when full screen pressed

Tags: windows-7, video, hdmi, nvidia-geforce

I've connected a 40' Philips 40PFL7605H as an external (second) monitor to GTX 275 card via HDMI. OS is Windows 7, CPU Core i7, 4 GB RAM, etc.

It works okay, but when I press full screen in media player (classic), the video frame just freezes.

Actually, when I just resize the video player window it freezes after certain (almost full screen) size. A bit smaller - it works, a bit bigger - freezes.

This does not depend on the video format or resolution.

I'm a bit confused: how should I debug this issue? Should I start with drivers, codecs, media player, HDMI cable or something else? It seems that some resource is lagging, but which one?

There are so much options and I don't even know where to start and what to check for. Please give some advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's the driver and/or video card. There's too much data for it to handle at that size, so it seizes up.