# Black screen & buzzing on full screen HDMI

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, freeze, hdmi

I have an Asus G46v Republic of Gamers laptop running Windows 10 OS, intel Core i5, and nvidia GEFORCE GTX 660M 2gb card.

About 2 months ago I dual-booted Ubuntu on it so that it takes up basically half of the partition space, maybe a little more and haven't gotten rid of it yet even though I mean to.

I recently got out my monitor again after about 2 months of not using it and now have my laptop connected to my monitor via an HDMI cable and whenever I click on full screen on a YouTube video, I get an all black screen with a non-stop buzzing sound.

This only happens when I do this on my monitor with the HDMI and not when I'm just using my laptop by itself.

I dual-booted Ubuntu after I stored my monitor away.

I've never had this problem, it just started happening.

From what I read on [this other SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/283401/video-playback-on-hdmi-connected-tv-freezes-when-full-screen-pressed), it seems like this is a result of the re-partitioning of space for Windows on my laptop and it no longer being able to handle the full-screen state on the monitor as a result but I just wanted to hear other people's thoughts.

*** Update ***

Well, I removed Linux, adjusted the windows partition accordingly so that it now has 676 GB of space and 80% of it is "free", and fixed the boot menu, but I'm still getting a black screen when going full screen when hooked up via HDMI.

I'm also getting a blue screen on the laptop with a stupid :( face and this:

"error: Driver IRQL Not Less or Equal (dxgmms1.sys)"

No clue.

*** Update #2 ***

Following some advice in [this forum topic](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-1627862/computer-freezes-youtube-videos.html), I went ahead and disabled "accelerated hardware" under "System" in my Chrome settings and the bug has not been present since then.

However, I still have a suspicion that there may be a fundamental issue with my NVIDIA drivers and was going to use [this tool](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) to try and fix it, but since the change I made in Chrome seems to be working, I'll go ahead and hold off for now.

*** Update #3 ***

So through a youtube video (SuperUser doesn't let me post a third link w/less than 10 reputation) I heard about the DriveTheLife driver updating/management software, which now goes by the name "DriverTalent", and was able to successfully update my drivers! I purchased a wired Xbox 360 controller to use for controller supported Steam games (i.e. DarkSouls), and after installing and using this software, my controller was recognized and had the correct drivers automatically installed for it!

After this success, seeing as I had all my display and Nvidia drivers updated, I decided to see if the original "Black screen & buzzing" issue would be gone. So, I disable "accelerated hardware" in my Chrome settings, opened up a YouTube video, and pressed the full-screen option.

Result: Issue persists.

As this is the case, I speculate that the issue may be from nvidia updates, maybe, but honestly, I don't really know at this point.

For now, I went ahead and turned off "accelerated hardware" in my Chrome settings again, and I'm satisfied with that for now, but it would be great to know more about this issue or if others encounter it and what they think is the root issue.

Feel free to weigh in :)

Comment: I recommend you to perform a downgrade, as long as no elimination of the problem in newer versions of the drivers occur . Maybe Asus offers a new version of the driver to fix the problem.

Comment: I actually ended up switching to elementary os.

Answer (score -2):

-it caused by Windows anniversary update, which somehow start a conflict between dual graphic card computer (Intel HD + Nvidia Geforce (or AMD)).

-it has 2 problem, first you cant put a video to fullscreen in "second screen only" display mode while using apps with graphical enhancements (like chrome, windows "Movie & Tv apps") but you can safely use VLC player apps. second you cant duplicate your screen to external anymore, the second external screen is just black.

-the only thing to temporarily fix this is by going to device manager, on the display adapter, then disable Intel HD. both of your screen will now run on Geforce, you can duplicate screen and play any video in full again, but you'll lose abilities to reducing your screen brightness and also to put sleep your computer.

-i these bugs only hit intel 4rd gen processor or below. 
another unsuggested solution is by using your old Intel HD driver (windows 8) which included in the disc when bought the laptop. but that's buggy too. so dont.

n.b - i'm also using G46VW ROG